# jQuery Animate function & the Each function

Tags: jquery

I am validating some text inputs using the keyup function, and I want to run an animation of a check mark when the box is considered validated.

The problem is that as soon as I click into any input, the animation starts.  If you type once as soon as you click in, you will see the animation happen. I'm assuming the animation starts because i'm adding the class on `keyup`, which essentially get's triggered after you release your mouse to click into it.  Is there another way around that?

1. I increased the time to 5 seconds just while testing it
2. Why is it triggering all 3 animations since i'm using the `each` and the `next` functions.
3. Is there a way around having the animation start on `keyup`.

The gist of my code is below, see a live version here: http://jsfiddle.net/MhMCz/26/

```
$(':input').each(function(){
   var values = $(this).attr('value');

   $(this).keyup(function(){
      if( $(this).val() !== '' && $(this).val() !== values) {
        $(this).addClass('animated');
        $(this).next('span').html("<img src='http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1581/silk/16/tick.png' />");
    }
    else {
       $(this).removeClass('animated'); 
       $(this).next('span').html('');     
    }                
   });

   if ( $(this).next('span').hasClass('animated') ) { }
   else {
      $(this).next('span').animate({
           marginLeft: '10px'
        }, 5000, function(){
           alert("animation complete")
   });   
}
)};
```

Comment: How are you validating the inputs? Just not blank?

Comment: Yes, not blank and don't equal the default value

Comment: keyup fires when you release the key on the keyboard not your mouse.

Comment: Then i'm not sure what's triggering the animation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reconstructured your code a little, could be optimzed more but it looks quite nice:

http://jsfiddle.net/MhMCz/30/

```
$('form').on('focus focusin blur focusout keyup', ':input', function(e) {
    var val = this.value,
        def = this.defaultValue,
        $t = $(this),
        $check = $t.next('span');

    switch(e.type){
        case 'focus':
        case 'focusin':
            if( val == def ) {
               this.value = '';
               $t.addClass('active');
            }
        break;
        case 'blur':
        case 'focusout':
            if(val == '') this.value = def;
            $t.removeClass('active');
        break;
        case 'keyup':
            if(val != '' && val != def) {
                $check.animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    'margin-left': '10px'
                }, 'fast');
            } else {
               $check.animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    'margin-left': '100px'
               }, 'fast');   
            }
        break;
    }
});
```

The event delegation from "form" ist just for performance, see http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/4.

Comment: Thanks Simon, the animation does not get triggered a second time if I clear out the input and type again.

Comment: Yeah like I said I just reorganized your code and made it work from what I got, I'll add this functionality

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with switch statements, time to hit the books.

Comment: Well here you go, answer updated. Still not the best solution but it works imho.

Comment: Just a tip: analyse the code, play around with it. Best way to learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="Name" class="validate_me" valid_compare="Name" /><span></span><br />
<input type="email" id="email" value="Email" class="validate_me" valid_compare="Email" /><span></span><br />
<input type="phone" id="phone" value="Phone" class="validate_me" valid_compare="Phone" /><span></span><br />
```

​

```
$(function(){
    $('.validate_me').keyup(function(){
        var this_val = $(this).val();
        var valid_compare = $(this).attr("valid_compare");

        if (this_val != "" & this_val != valid_compare ){
            $(this)
                .next()
                .css("margin-left","100px")
                .html("<img src='http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1581/silk/16/tick.png' />")
                .animate({
                    marginLeft: '10px'
                }, 1000, function(){
            });   
        } else {
            $(this).next().html("");
        }
    });
});​
```

**Here is a working example with keyup():** http://jsfiddle.net/9gg3n/4/

So I have added a custom attribute to wach of the input fields to compare against for validation (eg: != Name, != Email etc...). When the user moves types (keyup()) it checks if it's valid, and animates the tick if it is

Comment: It makes more sense (if I am understanding you correctly). You could also use keydown. Let me make yo ua jsfidle quick to show what I mean, gimme 5

Comment: Because I'm already using the blur function in-tandem with the focus function.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, however this does not work as the user types.  As soon as the text input isn't empty I want to trigger the animation. Not on focusout.

Comment: You can change the blur() to keyup() if you prefer

Comment: It now animates like it should however, it now triggers on every keyup so it will jump from left to right on every key press

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can figure it out from here. Use hide() & show()